# How to apply a pre-trained model of 3 channel images on single channel images?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe, nvidia-digits

I tried to used a pre-trained model that already was trained on three-channel color images, however, I am getting an error because of shape difference. Could someone let me know how can I tackle this issue? 
One user had suggested using `Tile` layer, but I could not find any relevant document/help for using this layer or any other solution. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You could send the same channel data to all three if you don't want to retrain the model.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail. I am not expert in the area.

Comment: I am assuming you have grayscale image. You could convert it to rgb image by repeating grayscale values in the rgb channels. There is opencv function like `rgb = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)` to do that too. Then you can use that image to your pretrained model.

Comment: @Inman: Do you know how this changes performance (e.g. accuracy of a classification network)? I have no idea if we speak about -5% on Top5 ImageNet accuracy or rather  -30%

Comment: @MartinThoma You are right we have no idea how it will perform. That is why in his previous question I suggested him to retrain if he needs transfer learning to work. Another option could be recovering rgb image from grayscale using deep learning. I read a paper somewhere about this. But that is a long shot.

Comment: @Inman: [Deep Colorization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00075.pdf) - I know this technique, but I didn't suggest it I don't think he would be able to do it. (But Deep Colorization vs Retraining with Grayscale would be an interesting comparison!)

Comment: @MartinThoma Yes, I thought that too. Thanks for the link. It might be an interesting comparison. S.EB could shed some light on the performance for now.

Comment: @lnman Thanks for your suggestion, It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

There is not much information in `caffe.proto` about tile layer. If you look at the code it just copies data `tiles` times for each outer dimension. For your case it should be:

```
layer{
    name: "tile"
    type: "Tile"
    bottom: "bottom-blob"
    top: "top-blob"
    tiling_param {
        // axis is 1 by default
        tiles: 3
    }
}
```